# Many-to-many relationship multiple drop-downs widget

Tags: python, django, widget

I am using Django1.9. I have a many-to-many relationship in my model between Person and Language. I want to find a way to select a language in html  widget(drop-down), and after selecting one language another drop-down should appear below, allowing selecting of one more language. One person can maximum have 8 languages.

My questions is how to implement it in Django? Should I create a custom widget for such case?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is what you are looking after
https://github.com/goinnn/django-multiselectfield